# snort doesn't alert other host port scanning

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, snort

I have this configuration:vmware debian11 running snort, vmware kali Linux running nmap that scans ports of Debian 11(real).
snort doesn't alert port scanning in this case.
instead if I scans ports of vmware Debian 11 running snort, it alerts

snort.conf (v.2.9):

```
preprocessor sfportscan: proto { all } \
    scan_type { all } \
    sense_level { high } \
    logfile { alert } \
    watch_ip { 192.168.1.8, 192.168.1.23 }
```

vmware machines are in bridge
any help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for snort to work properly, there is a need to activate the promiscuous mode on the virtual machine.
it is very simple to do, just follow these directions (for vmware player):
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/287